# database creation using dynamic memory allocation in C

Tags: c

I am new to programming and dont know much about linked list... help me in coding a program--

Take data from users and create your database.

```
          a>Data: Name, Age, Date of birth
          b>Memory for each entry should be dynamically created.
```

I have created a structure- 
struct database{
    char name[25];
    int age[5];
    int dob[10];
    struct database *next;
    };
Tell me how to proceed now...

Comment: For allocating memory dynamically in `C`, look for `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: yes definitely i have to use malloc and free but i dnt knw how to create link list.. inside linked list only i'll be using malloc and free,,, right??

Comment: look it up in the introductory book that you are using. Please don't tell me you are planning on learning programming by asking questions on stackoverflow. That would be a poor way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct database {
     char name[25];
     int age[5];
     // in my opinion you should only keep dob, since age would have to be constantly updated
     int dob[10]; 
     struct database *next; 
     } TCel, *TList, **Alist;
```

The basic idea is that whenever you create a new cel, you use the 'next' pointer in order to chain it in the linked list. For instance you can add a new cell at the end of the list:

```
AList InsEnd(AList aL, Info e)  
{ 
    TLista aux;
    // allocate cel and set the information inside it
    aux = AlocCel(e);                     
    if (!aux) return aL;               
    while (*aL != NULL) 
       aL = &(*aL)->next; 
    // linking the node
    *aL = aux;                            
    return aL;                            
}
```

or

```
TList InsEnd2(TList aL, Info e)
{
    TLista aux;
    aux = AlocCel(e);
    if(!aux) return aL;
    while(aL->next != NULL)
        aL = aL->next;
    // linking the node
    aL->next = aux;
    return aL;
}
```

Comment: How to check error for data entered? means if someone entered 12345 as name, how to check it and print an error message, same for age also I want to ask..

Comment: For the given example all that should be done in the AlocCel function maybe? Anyway the questions you are asking are very basic. You can use either ASCII values or functions such as isdigit(char) or isalpha(char) from the ctype.h library. You might want to check out this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctype.h

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to give you the code, but these link will surely help you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

http://richardbowles.tripod.com/cpp/linklist/linklist.htm

Also its better to go back and refer the book (as pointed by David, in comments)

Comment: thnx 4 the link,,, its really gud,,,